# Does Ricoeur Elaborate His Essay in a Book?

Tags: meaning, ricoeur

I'm reading "[the model of the text : meaningful action considered as a text](http://www.jstor.org/stable/468410)" in *New Literary History* by Paul Ricoeur, and I'm wondering if there Ricoeur has a more extended treatment of this elsewhere in book form.